# Does the emf of an electrode potential change over time?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry

In an electrode potential with a salt bridge and high resistant voltmeter, does the emf change over time as the reactions occur?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Remember that the standard electrode potentials are for 298K at 1 atm of pressure and **1N concentration of reagents**. As the concentration of ions to be reduced at the cathode decreases the emf will fall as well and is reflected in the Nernst equation.$$E_{cell} = E^\circ_{cell} - \frac{RT}{nF}ln(Q)$$

Comment: what about the mercury button cells their emf is independent of concentration of ions so theoritically its constant 1.35V but varies 1 % over shelf life.

Comment: @Physicsapproval The mercury button cells have solid products and reactants, therefore, Q is a constant 1 and emf does not change.